# How to remove these blue bars/borders in checkbox in Kendo

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, kendo-ui, treeview

I am creating a treeview using

> kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource

I want to remove these highlighted border. It is there only when using treeview.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overwriting the following style using `!important`. I overwritten it with red color, you can change it to any color of your choice.

```
.k-state-selected, 
.k-state-selected:link, 
.k-state-selected:visited, 
.k-tool.k-state-selected
{
 color : #ffff;
 background-color:#ff0000!important;
}
```

Sample [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/umaZaFuZ/2)

Comment: Hey this gives me a partial solution:
when i click it the font also turns to white

Comment: what do you mean by partial solution?

Comment: you can change the color:#ffff to color:black!important. It was just to give how to overwrite, you can always overwrite any style of kendo in similar way

Comment: This code works:
.k-state-selected, .k-state-selected:link, .k-state-selected:visited, .k-tool.k-state-selected
    {
     color : #000000;
     background-color:#ffffff!important;
    }

Thanks!

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it resolved your query

Comment: cab you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663690/bind-kendo-hierarchicaldatasource-treeview-to-remote-data-with-multiple-service

Anything that can help me